# Comparing an unknown type against a negative value

Tags: c, unsigned-integer, platform-agnostic

I have a variable `id` whose type may vary from platform to platform. In several places, existing code (which I cannot change) sets the `id` to a "negative" value, e.g.

```
id = -ETIMEDOUT;
```

On some platforms, `id` might be signed; on others, it may be unsigned. I want to test to see if the `id` was set to `-ETIMEDOUT`. The naive attempt below subtly fails when `id` is unsigned:

```
if(id == -ETIMEDOUT)
```

How do I concisely test for this condition?

Comment: Why not just test `if(id == (idtype)-ETIMEDOUT)`, where `idtype` is whatever type `id` is declared as (likely a `typedef`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jlahd has posted a good answer. I would like to offer an alternative though.

```
if (id == (typeof(id)) -ETIMEDOUT)
```

I think that this will do similar but there is a problem with it. It isn't in the C standard and is a GCC extension.

You can read a little more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081502/typeof-operator-in-c)

**Verbatim quote of @rici's comment:**

> Since you probably know some typedef which works as the type of id, you can presumably do this without typeof, although that is cleaner. However, it should be

```
(typeof(id))(-ETIMEDOUT)
```

> (the parentheses around -ETIMEDOUT are just cosmetic but the unary minus is required.) Alternatively, the following should be pretty well foolproof:

```
if (-id == ETIMEDOUT)
```

> since if id is signed, that obviously works; if id is unsigned, then unary minus has well-defined behaviour.

Comment: Since you probably know some typedef which works as the type of `id`, you can presumably do this without `typeof`, although that is cleaner. However, it should be `(typeof(id))(-ETIMEDOUT)` (the parentheses around `-ETIMEDOUT` are just cosmetic but the unary minus is required.) Alternatively, the following should be pretty well foolproof: `if (-id == ETIMEDOUT)`, since if `id` is signed, that obviously works; if `id` is unsigned, then unary minus has well-defined behaviour.

Comment: @rici I quite like your comment, I will include it verbatim in my answer with a credit if you don't mind.

Comment: @rici If you decide to make this an answer of your own please let me know and I will remove the edit. A comment under here will probably be the best way to get my attention.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
id += ETIMEDOUT;
if(id == 0) { /* timed out */ }
id -= ETIMEDOUT; /* if you need to keep id untouched */
```

Comment: Lol, before anyone gets a chance to say that this won't work on a "non two's complement arithmetic machine" I would like to ask them to name one that is in use today before posting the reply...

Comment: @nonsensical: well, actually, it's UB if you overflow a signed int. Compilers are allowed to do "unexpected" things in that case even if the system is twos-complement.

Comment: +1 -- This solution is reasonable, but it is somewhat cumbersome especially if I have to end up testing a half-dozen errnos.

Comment: @nneonneo Correct. However, I would argue that since this is C, unless you want an extremely inefficient code, your compiler will never check for overflow and this will be left to hardware which handles it in a defined way. But ok, standard does say that it's UB.

Comment: @nonsensical: in certain cases, the compiler can compile away checks that depend on UB. (The most prominent example is infinite loops when doing e.g. `for(int i=5; i != 4; i++)`; the compiler can optimize away the test even though it should eventually wraparound and terminate).

Comment: @nneonneo Hmm, I did not see that example before. It is a very interesting point. Thanks a lot, I've learned something new. So the only way to force that would be to use `unsigned i=5...`? See, this is why I love stackoverflow.

Comment: @nonsensical: yeah, you'd need to use `unsigned`. (The classical example of a nasty signed overflow optimization is a test like `i > i-1`; this is normally just optimized to `true` by the compiler, even if it is false under certain circumstances).