# c++ declare variable by size of type instead of type

Tags: c++

Is there any way to define a variable in C++ by specifying the types size instead of the size itself? Or is there a way to return a *type* from a function?

```
template<typename T, int L>
class vector {
    public:
    T* __vector;
};

#ifdef USE_FLOAT
typedef vector<float, 3> vec3
#else
typedef vector<double, 3> vec3;
#endif

void myFunc(vec3) {
    float a = vec3.__vector[0];
    // AAHHH but what if vec3 is a vector of doubles?
    // I can get the size of the type by
    int s = sizeof(vec3[0]);
    // So can I declare a variable by just giving the size of the variable?
}
```

Alternatively, is there anyway to have an accessor function in the class that can return the template typename?

Any suggestions would be helpful. I know there are other ways around this issue, but I'm specifically wondering if either of these two things are possible. (I'm less hopeful for the second method.)

I think the first way is possible by using a void pointer and malloc'ing... But I'd rather avoid using the heap and just stick with the stack if that is possible.

EDIT:

Just to clarify, I don't think `auto` would be helpful in my particular situation, though I did not explain why. This is more complete code and explains why I don't think (could definitely be wrong) that `auto` would not solve the issue.

I have another class matrix defined similarly.

```
template<typename T, int L>
class matrix {
    public:
    T* __matrix;
};

#ifdef USE_FLOAT
typedef matrix<float, 4> mat4;
#else
typedef matrix<double, 4> mat4;
#endif
```

And my myFunc functions looks more like this:

```
void myFunc(vec3) {
    float a = vec3.__vector[0];
    // AAHHH but what if vec3 is a vector of doubles?
    // I can get the size of the type by
    int s = sizeof(vec3[0]);
    // So can I declare a variable by just giving the size of the variable?

    matrix<sameTypeAsVec3, 4> mat();
}
```

I just don't think I could figure out that type with `auto`. But I'd love to be wrong!

Comment: as a fast-fix you can introduce one more macro, say, `NUM_TYPE` and make it either `float` or `double` depending on your `USE_FLOAT` macro. Then NUM_TYPE can be used in the rest of your code, in particular, in `myFunc`

Comment: Which language are we talking about here?

Comment: Sorry about that. Strictly speaking, I was interested in a C way to declare a variable by size of the variable without malloc'ing a void pointer. But my issue can be solved by other C++ means as has been pointed out below.

Comment: Most simply by use of `auto`, or a `typedef` inside the `USE_FLOAT` block  (Post edit: use `decltype`)

Comment: You shouldn't use [reserved names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) like `__vector`.

Comment: `matrix<sameTypeAsVec3, 4> mat();` doesn't define variable, but declare a function, you may want `matrix<sameTypeAsVec3, 4> mat;` or `matrix<sameTypeAsVec3, 4> mat{};` instead.

Comment: In your case, it seems that you want `mat4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ Solution, as the above code is in C++:

You can declare a public typedef member in your vector class like this:

```
template<typename T, int L>
class vector {
    public:
    T* __vector;

    typedef T value_type; //here
};
```

Then, you can use this member to get the type of the values in your vector:

```
void myFunc(vec3 vec) {
    //declares a to be of the same type as tye elements of vec
    vec::value_type a = vec.__vector[0];
```

This has the added advantage of relying entirely on the `vec3` API, allowing you to change how `vec3` is implemented without breaking your function.

Answer (score 6):

In C++11, you may use `auto` to let the compiler deduce the correct type, or `decltype`:

```
auto a = vec3.__vector[0];
```

And with `std::vector`, you have `value_type` which is the value type, i.e `std::vector<float>::value_type` is `float`.

Comment: Only in C++11 or above.

Comment: @inspector-g: I don't see any restriction of the standard for OP.

Comment: You're right, no obvious restriction, but without noting the C++11 requirement he may not configure his compiler correctly for C++11 support and end up with compilation errors.

Comment: I was not explicit in why this would be less helpful. But the issue I was having was actually because I tried to declare a mat4 (following the same name and typedef conventions) but I couldn't get the type from the vec3. So I don't think this would be helpful.

Comment: If we're using C++11, you can use `decltype` to get the type from an expression without evaluating it.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. Your answer is great for how ambiguous I was. Do you think it could still be relevant in the situation I described?

Comment: @phileaton: You can get the type as `decltype(vec3.__vector[0])`, if you need it in a context where you can't use `auto`. (Assuming you're not living in the past of course; in which case define a nested `typedef` as another answer describes).

Answer (score 3):

So. You have a type that changes based on some macro. **So let's give that type a name!**

```
#ifdef USE_FLOAT
typedef float custom_float;
#else
typedef double custom_float;
#endif

typedef vector<custom_float, 3> vec3;

void myFunc(vec3) {
    custom_float a = vec3.__vector[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ has `auto` to do that kind of "type inference":

```
void myFunc(vec3) {
    float a = vec3.__vector[0];
    // AAHHH but what if vec3 is a vector of doubles?

    // OOHHH - then do this:
    auto b = vec3.__vector[0];
}
```

You mentioned C in your question, so just for the case it's relevant for you or any future visitor, gcc has a language extension [`typeof`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12081502/509868), which "returns a type":

```
void myFunc(vec3) {
    float a = vec3.__vector[0];
    // AAHHH but what if vec3 is a vector of doubles?

    // Using C? Do that instead:
    typeof(vec3.__vector[0]) b = vec3.__vector[0];
}
```

Edit: seeing your recent version of the question, `auto` doesn't really help you. C++ has the other closely-related feature for that: `decltype`. It works exactly like `typeof` in C, and does exactly what one would expect.

```
// Instead of this:
matrix<double, 4> mat;
matrix<float, 4> mat;

// Use this:
matrix<decltype(vec3.__vector[0]), 4> mat;
```

Its name is `decltype` rather than the more straightforward `typeof` to improve compatibility with C.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to define a variable in C++ by specifying the types size instead of the size itself?

No. This would be ambiguous, since `int32_t`, `uint32_t`, `const uint32_t` etc. are all the same size.

> Or is there a way to return a type from a function?

Not exactly, but you can get the return type of a function, without evaluating it, using `decltype`.

---

Anyway, you actually want something like:

```
void myFunc(vec3 vec) {
    matrix<sameUnderlyingTypeAsVec3, 4> mat();
}
```

Now, if your `matrix` and `vector` classes are part of some library, it's entirely reasonable to add typedefs to the class templates, or to add your own traits class.

Or, you can use `decltype`.

Or, you can make this function a template itself - it'll be selected based on your conditional compilation anyway:

```
template <typename T, int N>
void myFunc(vector<T,N> const &vec) {
    matrix<T, N> mat();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach (no additional typedefs or macros, no requirement for C++11) would be to use a templated function for this:

```
template <typename ContainedType>
void myFunc(vector< ContainedType, 3 > vec)
{
    ContainedType a = vec.__vector[0];
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    vec3 vec;
    myFunc(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

You mentioned wanting to use other lengths than 3, so an even more general approach would be to change your vector class thusly:

```
template<typename T>
class vector
{
    public:
    T* mVector;
    int mLength;
    vector(int len)
    {
        this->mVector = new T[ len ];
        this->mLength = len;
    }
};
```

And change the function thusly:

```
template <typename ContainedType>
void myFunc(vector< ContainedType > vec)
{
    ContainedType a = vec.mVector[0];
    // If you need to know the length, access vec.mLength;
}
```