# How can i recognise an Integer array contains characters in C?

Tags: c

Scenario :-

> My array contains elements  like 56,12,ew34,45 or 56,12,34rt,45 how
>   can I show  that the array is not integer array?

```
var Array =[56,12,'ew34',45 or 56,12,'34rt',45];
```

> Actually  am trying to find a solution with out Inbuilt Functions.

Comment: What is the data type of the array?

Comment: Is the array declared as an array of integers? Then it contains only integers. It would help if you could be more specific, like telling us *what* the array is, to show us its declaration.

Comment: An integer array, by definition, cannot contain anything other than integers. Perhaps you are asking whether any of the integers in the array are in the valid range for ASCII characters?

Comment: data type of the array is integer.If I input any characters other than integers it should return 0 else return 1.@Pang

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to detect character sequences (strings) that look like integers. Please show us what you have already tried.

Comment: Hi, I suppose that you create an char array to store the input from user (via console or sth else), and then you need to check whether the input contains non-numeric char. If this assumption is correct, you should check the function strtol [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)

Comment: Did you mean... `if ( ( ret = scanf("%d", &arr[i]) ) != 1 ) return (0) ;` ?

Comment: @mauro +1 That seems what OP's looking for.

Comment: I tried this @merlin2011:
arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*len);
 for (i=0; i < len; i++)
 {
  if (scanf("%d", &arr[i] !=1))
   return NULL;
 }
where len is any integer.(let len=5)
Now,I enter some elements like 24,34,r23,5k,99
and I should return 0 as there are non-inegers like r23 and 5k.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- please refer it before posting your Query

Comment: @nikhilkumar What you're looking for is already covered by scanf. All you need to do is to check if scanf returns a zero, which means that things other than integers are detected and that scanf cannot further proceed.

Comment: You already seem to check for non-integers in your reading loop (please edit your question to include such information), so I don't really see the problem (except the memory leak and the syntax error you have from re-writing the code in your comment). Can you please edit your question to elaborate on the problem you have with the code you tried?

Comment: got it.thanks every one :)

Answer (score 0):

If array is declared as integer type then it won't accept any char type data.
If you are trying to insert 0 instead of char type data, handle the same conveniently at the insertion time.
Also you can make use of compiler extension [typeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081502/typeof-operator-in-c).