# Type of a variable in language C

Tags: c, variables

How to know the type of a variable in C ?

I tried **sizeof()** but i'm not convinced by the answer and i don't know how to use **typeof()** in C.

Some help ?

If we have for example : 
`int i ;` 
then what is the type of ('A' + i). i though i can do something like 
`printf("%s", typeof('A' + i));` 
to display the right type of my expression but i don't kwon how work a **gcc expression**.

Help please !

Comment: there is no reflection in C.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you're trying to do?

Comment: C is statically typed, so looking up variable's declaration gives you its exact data type.

Comment: Like @HuStmpHrrr said, there's no way in C. What is your use case? Maybe there is an alternative solution.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081502/typeof-operator-in-c

Comment: You do not have the luxury of disbelieving the result of the `sizeof` operator.  If your compiler were so badly broken that it did not compute sizes correctly then you pretty much could not rely on it for *anything*.  If `sizeof` produces a result that surprises you then it's probably because you have some misunderstanding about the operand.

Comment: If we have for exemple : int i ; then what is the type of ('A' + i). i though i can do something like printf("%s", typeof('A' + i)); to display the right type of my expression but i don't kwon how work a gcc expression.

Answer (score 1):

Introspection/reflection and is not supported in C language. However, there is a `typeof` [extension](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuexts.html#SEC69) in GCC (not part of ANSI)

Comment: If we have for exemple : int i ; then what is the type of ('A' + i). i though i can do something like printf("%s", typeof('A' + i)); to display the right type of my expression but i don't kwon how work a gcc expression.

Comment: This is not how it works, the typeof extension basicly allows you to do declare a variable using the type of another variable. It's similar to the auto keyword in C++.