# C Pointer To Anonymous Struct

Tags: c

Is there a way to get a pointer to an anonymous struct? With out anonymous structs I could write the following:

```
struct a{
    int z;
};
struct b{
    int y;
    struct a *x;
}
```

This works fine, but I only use `struct a` within `struct b` and it seems redundant to pollute the global namespace with it. Is there a way I could define a pointer (`x`) to an anonymous struct. Something that would probably look like the following:

```
struct b{
    int y;
    struct {
        int z;
    } *x;
}
```

Or is this valid on its own?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you can do this. But there is a complication: there is no way to directly declare another pointer to same type - or an object of that type, because... the struct type is anonymous.

It is still possible to use it however, by allocating memory for it with `malloc`, as conversions from `void *` to any pointer to object are possible without an explicit cast:

```
struct b {
    int y;
    struct {
        int z;
    } *x;
} y;

y.x = malloc(sizeof *y.x * 5);
```

Why would you think that this is better than polluting the namespace is beyond my imagination.

---

GCC provides the `typeof` so you can increase insanity by things like

```
typeof(y.x) foo;
```

or even declare a structure of that type

```
struct b y;
typeof(y.x[0]) foo;
foo.z = 42;
y.x = &foo;
```

Comment: Thank you, but my question was only if that way of defining a struct was valid.

Comment: @BElgy Yes, of course it is. But that's not what you asked in the title. Or that's not where the problem is.