# Is there a way to declare a function argument to take an anonymous enum?

Tags: c, enums

If I have an anonymous enum, is there any way to pass a value of that type to a function? For example,

```
typedef struct {
    enum { On, Off } status;
    int max_amps;
} SWITCH;

void make_switches(){
    SWITCH switch1 = createSwitch( On, 15 );
    SWITCH switch2 = createSwitch( Off, 20 );
}

SWITCH* createSwitch( ??? status, int max_amps ){
    SWITCH* new_switch = malloc( sizeof( SWITCH ) );
    new_switch->status = status;
    new_switch->max_amps = max_amps;
    return new_switch;
}
```

I would like to pass the value of the anonymous enum into the `createSwitch()` function. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm sure you already thought of this, but my suggestion is to promote the `enum` to be a global, named type.

Comment: Sure, you can `SWITCH *createSwitch(int status...)`

Comment: The value of an enumeration is similar to an integer, you can accept `status` as any type of integer

Comment: Replacing `???` with `typeof(On)` is a really bad idea for many reasons, not the least of which is that it isn't mentioned in the C specification. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081502/typeof-operator-in-c

Comment: @user3386109: I guess I'm blind; where do you see`typeof(On)` ?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I guess wry humor doesn't work, sigh.

Comment: Consider [What is the size of an enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/366017/2410359): the size of the argument is not known.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have suggested, you can simply use an `int` in the place of `???`.

This is because as per [6.7.2.2/3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2p3) of [C11](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) standard (Committee draft):

> The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type `int` and may appear wherever such are permitted.