# UISlider / touch events changes in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've encountered a problem with iOS 7 which I believe is related to the way events are handled.
I have  a slider which upon changing it's value does some image processing which takes about 100ms to complete. In iOS 6, I could see the image change as the slider is dragged. After upgrading to iOS 7 it seems that the view is not redrawn between invocations of the value changed events. While dragging the slider, I can see the image processing start and finish numerous times but the entire view doesn't refresh (including the slider's thumb) until I stop sliding. Also the same happen when I add a gesture handler to the view which does the same thing. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It would greatly help if we saw some code here. I *think* I understand what you're saying, but any additional info is helpful, code, images of the issue, something other than a wall of text.

Comment: Have you tried manually calling `setNeedsDisplay`?

Comment: Yes I have tried calling setNeedsDisplay but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not doing that processing on the main thread. I recommend using GCD to dispatch the processing onto a separate queue - it takes very little code and uses a [well established pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903247/ios-process-data-without-freezing-the-ui) that is easy to understand.

Comment: I thought about doing the processing in a background thread but it would require some more work on my side since I'll need the processing to take action sequentially and not simultaneously (unless you can point me to something like a work queue that performs the actions in the background but sequentially). Also, it works perfectly in iOS 6 and the image processing doesn't take too much time but I'll probably go this route if everything else fails.

Comment: @idan You can use a GCD serial queue for that.

Comment: Apple *strongly* recommends doing any processing you can on a different queue than the UI. The effort to implement it is very low, and the payoff is quite high. You can use serial queues if it's a simple "do A, then B, then C" type of task, or if you have dependencies between the tasks NSOperationQueue makes that trivial to implement.

Comment: After adding a serial queue the situation has improved much but still it is not as good as it was in iOS 6. What I eventually did is add a serial queue and each time the slider changes a work item is added and all previous work items are removed. So basically you would have to wait for at most one item to finish before the current one starts. The main issue that remains is that I have a gesture handler which affects an image mask as the user draws. Obviously I can't do the trick of cancelling previous work items and this causes a delay between drawing and actually seeing the effect on screen

Comment: If you need to cancel the previous work item, use NSOperationQueue. Then your work blocks need to check frequently if they should be cancelled. If you gave us more information in the question regarding what kind of image processing, we can probably be more helpful.